# Suspend devmapper target when underlying device removed

Tags: udev, block-device, device-mapper

If you create a table with `dmsetup` and the underlying device gets forced removed, the target will begin to throw I/O errors.

Is there any way to specify that the target should suspend itself if any of its dependencies are no longer available?

Could `udev` possibly be configured to execute `dmsetup suspend` on device removal? (Although I am trying to avoid `udev` as much as possible).

Comment: by the time `udev` executes `dmsetup suspend`, you'll already have I/O errors if such I/O operations were ongoing at the time of removal. for a proper solution the storage layer has to cooperate, something like dm-multipath or similar.

Comment: then what happens to the storage device while removed is an entire other can of worms. anything modifies it in any way, which the suspended device does not expect, corruption follows. devices are busy and must not be removed for a reason after all

Comment: Sure, but I'm dealing with recovering flaky drives that disconnect after X seconds and I want my recovery setup to 'suspend' until I fix the problem.

Comment: @frostschutz - When you say dm-multipath do you have something specific in mind?

Comment: No, nothing specific. `ddrescue` already knows how to resume, so maybe you're looking for a way to automate that with `udev` instead? Getting the device mapper to deal with it doesn't seem to be trivial...

Comment: @frostschutz What!? I've never seen that in `ddrescue` - if the drive `sdc` drops out and reappears as `sdd` on the same port, how can I get ddrescue to resume that? Unless you mean manually... but my whole setup revolves around automating power cycling etc.

Comment: You should be able to get udev to resume ddrescue, thus automate the manual step.